# failed to sync grade project

Tags: android, build.gradle

After adding this line to my build.gradle

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.1"

  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And syncing gradle file. I get this error
[image: Error]

Then I follow the link to open Android SDK Manager and I find that I have already installed Android Suport Repository

[image: Showing I have installed Android Support Repository]

The reason I am adding this file to my grade is because it has been posted that this will solve my initial error where

```
 Cannot resolve symbol 'TabsPagerAdapter'
```

Comment: You put the `compile` line in the wrong place in your `build.gradle` file, based on the error message. You might consider editing your question and posting your full `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Ok, I made your suggested edits. Where are you suppose to put the compile line?

Comment: Matias' answer covers that. FWIW, I filed [a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=228489) about the incorrect suggestion to install the Android Support Repository. Also, regarding `TabsPagerAdapter`, there is no such class in the Android SDK that I can find, so that would appear to be a separate problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line: `compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.1"` goes inside the other build.gradle file.. you are adding it on the main build.gradle, you should add that inside the specific gradle file for your app module.